# Do many simple linear regressions require adjustment for multiple comparisons?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have encountered a situation where someone has run many simple linear regressions, each on a separate subset of data, to test for changes in a slope in some time-series data. Each month, a new data value is added to the end of the dataset and data point at the start of the dataset is removed. The idea with some sample data looks like the following:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(Month = rep(1:12,3),
                Value = c(rep(50:39,2),runif(n=12,min=40.98,max=50.02)),
                Attribute = rep(c("Var1","Var2","Var3"),each=12)) 
df$Value = ifelse(df$Attribute == "Var1",df$Value + rnorm(n=12,mean=0,sd=2),
              ifelse(df$Attribute == "Var2", df$Value + rnorm(n=12,mean=0,sd=5),
                     df$Value))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Month, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm',se=F)+
  facet_wrap(~Attribute,ncol=3,scales="free_y")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Where the results of simple linear models are:

```r
summary(lm(Value~Month,data = subset(df,df$Attribute=="Var1")))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Value ~ Month, data = subset(df, df$Attribute == 
#>     "Var1"))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -5.0317 -1.0829  0.1094  0.9651  4.4806 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  49.1870     1.6113  30.526 3.34e-11 ***
#> Month        -0.7823     0.2189  -3.573  0.00507 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.618 on 10 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.5608, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5169 
#> F-statistic: 12.77 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.005068
```

```
summary(lm(Value~Month,data = subset(df,df$Attribute=="Var2")))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Value ~ Month, data = subset(df, df$Attribute == 
#>     "Var2"))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -7.1860 -2.9841 -0.2995  2.9611  8.8702 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  54.8803     3.0021  18.281 5.16e-09 ***
#> Month        -1.4304     0.4079  -3.507  0.00566 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 4.878 on 10 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.5515, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5067 
#> F-statistic:  12.3 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.005663
```

```
summary(lm(Value~Month,data = subset(df,df$Attribute=="Var3")))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Value ~ Month, data = subset(df, df$Attribute == 
#>     "Var3"))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.1464 -1.5691  0.7905  1.3470  2.8691 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 45.706605   1.297132  35.237 8.04e-12 ***
#> Month       -0.006244   0.176246  -0.035    0.972    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.108 on 10 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.0001255,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.09986 
#> F-statistic: 0.001255 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.9724
```

Here, we see that the relationship between `Value` and `Month` does not have a significant slope within the `Var3` subset. Though this example includes only 3 simple linear regressions, the real situation uses many more.

**Question:** Do the p-values associated with each of these simple linear regression require adjustment for multiple comparisons?

It seems that this is a point of discussion, but generally pertaining to the use of multiple regression, rather than say, a t-test. However, using simple linear regression in this way seems to behave like a hypothesis test.

Answer (score 2):

Well...maybe.

It seems like you're estimating the slope for three groups within your data.  No matter what test one performs (the associated tests for OLS coefficients are t-tests, so your point about t tests is moot) the probability of making at least one type one error will increase.

That being said, if you're interested in performing these tests, I wonder if just doing an F test would be more appropriate, but it would depend on what question you are trying to answer.

Comment: Yes, good point on the t-tests vs. coefficients. I guess one further question is the use of this method in econometrics, which is the case used above. In econometrics, sampling doesn't seem to be treated in the same way, so is multiple-comparisons ever an issue?

Comment: @geoscience123 Its unquestionable the type one error rate inflates.  What researchers in different disciplines do is something orthogonal to the question at hand.

Comment: Subject matters enters in the sense of priors. In some areas there is strong prior theory that nulls are (at least approximately) true, so "searching for significance" by repeatedly testing the null with different data becomes highly likely to return a false significance. In finance, market efficiency is such a null. In psychology, lack of paranormal activity is such a null. In either case, repeated testing in the usual frequentist way with different data is likely to find evidence against the null, ie, evidence of market inefficiency and paranormal activity, respectively.